# a question on a paper by Matomaki and Radziwill

Tags: nt.number-theory

I'm not quite sure about Equation (16) in Lemma 12 in their annals paper Multiplicative functions in short intervals. The equation, which is independent on the context of the lemma, is as follows.
$$
\sum_{X\le n \le 2X} \frac{a_n}{n^s}=\sum_{P\le p \le Q}\ \sum_{X/p\le m\le 2X/p} \frac{a_{pm}}{(pm)^s}\cdot\frac{1}{\#\{P\le q\le Q:q|m, q\in \mathbb P\}+1}+\sum_{X\le n\le 2X, (n,\mathcal P)=1}\frac{a_n}{n^s}
$$
where $\mathcal P=\prod_{P\le p\le Q}p$. (And I believe $\mathbb P$ is the set of prime numbers.)

I don't see why this is true. For example, let's say $X\le P^2\le 2X$. Then the term $n=P^2$ is counted once on the left-hand side, but only half on the right-hand side.

Comment: Yes, this is a known small inaccuracy.  It makes little difference to the proof since it only affects numbers divisible by the square of a large prime, and there aren't so many of these.  See also http://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.08021.pdf and the comments around equation (53) there.